Pyrogram SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats
I built a telegram bot using Pyrogram and Im trying to deploy it on PythonAnyWhere.
I got this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Wle09/Bot-WK-V2.py", line 557, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 84, in run
    self.start()
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 66, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 58, in start
    is_authorized = await self.connect()
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/auth/connect.py", line 47, in connect
    await self.session.start()
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 149, in start
    raise e
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 117, in start
    await self.send(raw.functions.Ping(ping_id=0), timeout=self.START_TIMEOUT)
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 326, in send
    payload = await self.loop.run_in_executor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/crypto/mtproto.py", line 50, in pack
    return auth_key_id + msg_key + aes.ige256_encrypt(data + padding, aes_key, aes_iv)
  File "/home/Wle09/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyrogram/crypto/aes.py", line 30, in ige256_encrypt
    return tgcrypto.ige256_encrypt(data, key, iv)
SystemError: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN macro must be defined for '#' formats

I did some research and i found some solutions like updating library version but all that didn't work
what should i do to solve this problem?
